# All Internet apps in grayscale

Tags: settings

All Internet apps (chrome, Facebook, Gmail, YouTube) are only showing in grayscale. System settings don't seem to be the problem and all other apps show color.

Moto G5 power
Android v13

Comment: Are you talking about the app icons or the apps itself? If it is the first you may have enabled the aggressive battery saver which blocks most apps and disables them.

Comment: @Robert the apps themselves

Comment: This seems to be something to do with Digital Wellbeing, but since I can't get that to turn on, here's [a Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/1ak9dbl/a_few_of_my_apps_have_gone_into_greyscale_mode/) that seems very relevant.